# Does sizeof(int) (or any sizeof any simple data type) cost anything at runtime?

Tags: c++, sizeof

I would have thought that all the necessary info would be known at compile time and the compiler could insert a constant value.

Does this indeed happen?

Comment: No, `sizeof` is only compile-time.

Comment: Nothing else happens.

Comment: No because it happens at compile time.

Comment: Except VLAs, of course. (but that's C anyway.)

Comment: What about a statement like sizeof(int)-1? All data is known at compile time also - any cost there?

Comment: @AndrewS, if you compiler smart enough, it will optimize. I don't think any not smart enough used now

Comment: If compiler knows the value of `sizeof(int)` at compile-time itself, then it can know the value of `sizeof(int)-1` also, can't it? Or for that matter `sizeof(int) * 10000` or any such expressions involving "constant" sub-expressions.

Comment: @AndrewS. Technically, your compiler is free to be as dumb and inefficient as it wants to be so long as it gets the right result, but compilers you are likely to actually want to use are as smart as they can be. This can easily all be done at compile time.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, Is it required to be done at compile-time with `constexpr`?

Comment: @chris No. The compiler is free to be as dumb and inefficient as it wants to be, even if you go out of you way to help it be smart. Of course a compiler you are likely to actually use will be as smart as it can be and will in fact do it at compile time.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, That's pretty counter-intuitive when `constexpr` is available imo. Of course it is as you say, and a compiler would be crazy not to.

Comment: @AndrewS what does it matter if `sizeof(int)-1` is done at compile time or runtime? Is there some problem you're having that hinges on this?

Comment: @Nik - no, simple curiosity

Comment: @AndrewS that's actually a *good* reason!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `sizeof(int)` results in a constant expression of `size_t` type, which means its value known at compile time. NO RUNTIME OVERHEAD!

Comment: And `sizeof` won't work on VLAs in C++14, so it will retain that property.

Comment: @chris: did VLAs made it into C++14 ? I had seen talk of `std::dynamic_array` but no formal proposal for full VLAs.

Comment: @MatthieuM., Both VLAs and `std::dynarray` are in.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Yes. :-)

Answer (score 1):

No. It is a compile time thing.

Answer (score 1):

No, in C++, `sizeof` is always evaluated in compile time.

Note that it's not true in C, the exception is variable length arrays.